# Convert React-component to HTML-string (exporting to file)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to get the value in the return statement of a React component exported as a string.
So if I have a component

```
function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
    </div>
)
```

I want to run a function on it get the literal string  `"<div> <h1>Some content</h1> </div>"`

exported to another file. Is that possible?

Comment: What's the use case for this? Just curious.

Comment: Note that you can apply `.toString()` for a function to get its string representation but the problem is that since you are dealing with JSX, it will get transpiled to function calls and you'll lose your syntax as then it's already too late. I suspect you would have to write a transpiler plugin for the use case. I would have to know which transpiler you are using to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` for this. To do that first `import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server;` and then pass `SomeComponent` to the function as an argument. Finally export it like any other statement to make it useable in other files.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Some content</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export const SomeComponentAsString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
  <SomeComponent />
);
// <div><h1>Some content</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to this type of problem would be to use `.toString()` against a function and then parse what you need from there.

In this case, the problem is that given it's JSX, the code needs to be transpiled before it gets run. During this process the JSX markup will get transformed into function calls and therefore it's losing information you would need.

To overcome this problem, I would suggest into developing a plugin for your transpiler that's storing the function contents during the transpilation process. You could write `fn.jsx = 'jsx as string'` there for example.

To give more exact solution, I would have to know which transpiler you are using as each of them comes with an API of its own.